# error LNK1104: cannot open file 'cv.lib'

Tags: visual-studio, opencv

Error 2 error LNK1104: cannot open file 'cv.lib' D:\Data\VickY\OpenCV\Source Files\TestDetection_v.2\FaceDetection\LINK FaceDetection

Comment: you should not use any code, that depends on outdated opencv1.0

Answer (score 0):

You need to set you library link paths and lib names.